# python system's total transfer function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm working on modeling a system of different digital filters in Python (used as reference for an RTL implementation). For part of the chain I'm using several FIR filters in series. I would like to plot the total system frequency response. I know about `scipi`/`numpy`'s `signal.freqz()` function. But I don't know how to **combine all the different transfer functions** of the filters into one function for plotting.

The attached image gives a simplified view of my system:

[image: System overview]

Comment: I have to warn you that I don't understand FIRs too well. That said, doesn't it all come down to linear convolution in the end? So can't you use the convolution theorem? If I understand correctly (a big if as I said) FIRs satisfy something like y * b = x * a, so in the Fourier domain you would have y^ b^ = x^ a^, thus y^ = a^ / b^ x^. Does that make any sense?

Comment: Hi Paul I can follow your first 2 sentences, after that?
I've been experimenting a bit more and it looks like that for a FIR filter that is used 3 times in series Hseries = Hsingle**3. This can be calculated form in python like 
`w, h, = signal.freqz(num,dem)
h_series = h**3`
For now this looks like a solution for me.

Comment: Yes, that''s essentially what the convolution theorem predicts. Filtering, also filtering multiple times, is more or less the same as multiplying (pointwise, i.e. frequency by frequency) in the frequency domain. The issue is a bit muddled by the back-and-forth you do with FIRs, but in the end you seem to get the same behaviour, that's what I tried to derive in the other comment. Anyway, glad you got it to work for you.